# Decode/read a large PNG stream in chunks/parts of bitmap data instead of committing the entire file to memory

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, stream, .net-6.0

I am attempting to make a program that takes a PNG image from disk, modifies the RGB components of all pixels in the image (the transformation is just some basic math), and outputs/reencodes this to another output PNG image file on disk.

My problem is that the input images that I wish to run this program on are typically very large (8192x8192 up to 65535x65535). The naïve method of decoding the entire input PNG into a bitmap in memory (then transforming and reencoding) would far exceed the 8gb of memory my laptop provides me.

Is there any easy method that I can use to read and decode a large PNG stream in small buffers/chunks of bitmap data (thereby only ever allocating a small buffer instead of reading and decoding the entire file into memory) in .NET 6?. Or is this a situation where I must write my own decoder to allow for buffering and working on that buffer in this manner?

All images can be assumed to be 8-bit per channel RGB -- no alpha channel (Type 2), no interlacing (Type 0).

Comment: The possible solution is definitely related to the context of the problem. As a matter of fact, I did read your question multiple times. however, I didn't really find your problem context.  I mean, Are you dealing with large storage of Images that going to process these images, OR, The images (PNG files) are sent/received by the clients where you do not have a vision of the future, which may make your system out-of-memory.  so I recommend you explain a little more about your context.

Comment: @AFarmanbar I've made an edit to clarify the context of the issue. Hopefully it's less confusing, sorry if it's more confusing.

Comment: Just in case, I faced out-of-memory when dealing with images in C# and my main problem was that I did not properly dispose of the allocated memory. as you said, you were converting images to bitmaps therefore, you must carefully dispose of the bitmaps as recommended in official sources.

Comment: It is not so much a matter of disposing the memory as it is allocating it, a 65535x65535 image would require (if my math is correct) 11gb of memory which I find unacceptable and impossible to run on my own hardware.